# React Native alternative for reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, recaptcha

First of all, I already check this [lib](https://github.com/acsant/react-native-recaptcha) and other similar one which basically wrap everything inside a `WebView`, that's not useful. Also [this one](https://github.com/rajivshah3/react-native-google-safetynet) is only for `Android` based on safetynet. afaik there is no native solution for using reCaptcha for `ios`. I was wondering what is the alternative solution for avoiding users to spam in our forms inside a React Native mobile app?

I used invisible google reCaptcha for my web app which works fine, but now I making a native app, but couldn't find a solution for this, anyone have a spugestion?

I wondering if somehow we can verify the client by iOS/Android device identifier maybe?

Comment: why do you need captcha in a mobile app?

Comment: might help https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51864/captcha-on-mobile-what-are-the-alternatives

Comment: @madalinivascu well I implement a mobile app which use the same serverside logic as Web App, for my web app in order to submit a form I forced the server to check the reCaptcha Token, now I want create the mobile app and I need to validate the client on that step somehow.

Comment: you can pass a additional param from your mobile app to ignore the captcha check on mobile

Comment: @madalinivascu I can't just ignore it, still is possible to get spam

Comment: never heard of a mobile app getting spam